# regex remove line breaks between double quotes without affecting other line break (eager match)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, find

I have a `map` (key, value pairs) and few of these values have line breaks within them (inside double quotes) which is causing issues in CSS.

How can I remove these link breaks (the ones inside double quotes only) using regex find and replace (suitable in JavaScript).

Input:

```
  actionIconTransition: " background-color 0.2s,
  color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  listItemTransition:
    " background-color 0.2s,
  border-color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  primeIconFontSize: " 1rem",
  divider: " 1px solid #dee2e6",
```

Expected output:

```
  actionIconTransition: " background-color 0.2s,color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  listItemTransition:
    " background-color 0.2s,border-color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  primeIconFontSize: " 1rem",
  divider: " 1px solid #dee2e6",
```

I have tried many regexes but they are either removing line breaks in last two lines too, or don't do anything at all.

Comment: Thańk you for question, has the answer below worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
let test_str = `actionIconTransition: " background-color 0.2s,
  color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  listItemTransition:
    " background-color 0.2s,
  border-color 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s",
  primeIconFontSize: " 1rem",
  divider: " 1px solid #dee2e6",`
console.log(test_str.replace(/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g, (z) => z.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '')))
```

I.e. remove carriage return and line feed characters between quotes only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Adding it so that newbies get benefited.

The following regex select the line breaks only inside the double quotes or single quotes without affecting other lines

Find: `[^"'],\n`

Replace: `,`

Javascript code for doing the same

```
.replace(/[^"'],\n/gm,",");
```

The flags "gm" above is optional. Use it if your strings span across multiple lines and there are multiple occurences for the given pattern which needs to be replaced.

**Note: This answer is useful for my usecase. If anyone faces slightly different problem I can help with a regex with their usecase.**

Comment: This answer is not a good solution: the replace operation will delete the character matched by `[^"']`. You are also misunderstanding the use of the `m` flag - it is only needed if `^` or `$` is used.